# Report Data Sorted In Different Order Than Query

Tags: sorting, report, ms-access-2010

So I've run into an issue where my query data is sorted one way, however when viewing the report for this query the data is not shown in the sorted order.

How can I sort the data in the query and produce the report in the same sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Group & Sort" Properties (activate them with the "Group & Sort"-Button in the "Design" Ribbon-Tab) of the Report to sort the data in the report any way you like.

If it is a report without any group levels, you could remove all the sort settings for the report. Then it should be sorted the same way as your query.